# Cut content to next row maintaining other content in range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to cut the cells present from the cells in E1:G1 and add it to D2 and copy the cells in range present in A1:C1 to the next row,

[image]

and do that to next rows and so on in which they have content from the columns E to G.

I've already tried to use the "Data - Text to Columns" in Excel but I can't use that in order to copy to rows...

What I'm trying to obtain is in this format, but I'm having a hard time finding VBA code in order to do this.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I´m new to StackOverflow in the Future i´ll do my best efforts in order to at least show what I´ve been doing to solve the problem.

Comment: In regard of that I´ve tried to use some examples found here in StOverflow but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim Avalue As String, BValue As String, Cvalue As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1

            Avalue = .Range("A" & i).Value
            BValue = .Range("B" & i).Value
            Cvalue = .Range("C" & i).Value

            LastColumn = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            If LastColumn > 4 Then

                For y = LastColumn To 5 Step -1

                   .Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert

                    .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Avalue
                    .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = BValue
                    .Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Cvalue
                    .Cells(i, y).Cut .Cells(i + 1, 4)

                Next y

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Array Version**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim Avalue As String, BValue As String, Cvalue As String
    Dim ABCvalues As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1

            ABCvalues = .Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value

            LastColumn = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            If LastColumn > 4 Then

                For y = LastColumn To 5 Step -1

                    .Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert

                    .Range("A" & i + 1 & ":C" & i + 1).Value = ABCvalues

                    .Cells(i, y).Cut .Cells(i + 1, 4)

                Next y

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You could push ABC-Values into one array `Dim abcValues() As Variant: abcValues = .Range("A" & i, "C" & i).Value` and write them all at once like `.Range("A" & i+1, "C" & i+1).Value = abcValues` which should be faster because you save 2 read and 2 write actions.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ could you please evaluate Array Version answer?

Comment: You forgot to replace the reading part at `Avalue …` with `abcValues = .Range("A" & i, "C" & i).Value` • And remove `ABCvalues = Array(Avalue, BValue, Cvalue)`. Read it *directly* into the array.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ generally it s faster?to declare a variable, give it a value and then use the variable or use it directly?

Comment: Of course you could do it without an array :( my bad, didn't see that: `.Range("A" & i + 1 & ":C" & i + 1).Value = .Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value` should work directly. In general the less actions you do the faster it is. So read/write all 3 values at once is faster that read/write 3 times 1 value. • `Dim Avalue …` can also be removed then. So you could condese the answer to the direct version.

Comment: The Array version indicated is faster as sugested by @Error 1004, due to I had about 5000 rows to be analyzed